# Why file path not shown in text field after FilePicker picks up file? (Razor MAUI)

Tags: c#, .net, blazor, maui-blazor

I have the code in .razor like below. After I pick up the file, the input field will not show the path immediately. But if I click the button again, the path shows up suddenly. How can I change the codes?

```
<div>

    <label for="inputdata">Input Data:</label>
    <input type="text" name="inputdata" value="@filePath" />
    <button @onclick="OpenFileAsync">Open</button>

</div>

@code {

    private string filePath;

    public async void OpenFileAsync()
    {
        var customFileType = new FilePickerFileType(
            new Dictionary<DevicePlatform, IEnumerable<string>>
                {
                { DevicePlatform.WinUI, new[] { "jpg" } },
                }
        );

        PickOptions options = new()
        {
            PickerTitle = "Please select a comic file",
            FileTypes = customFileType,
        };
        var result = await FilePicker.Default.PickAsync(options);
        if (result != null)
        {
            filePath = result.FullPath;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [StateHasChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.componentbase.statehaschanged?view=aspnetcore-7.0) method to notify the component that its state has changed.

Just add this piece of code after filepath has been changed,

```
public async void OpenFileAsync()
{
    ...
    var result = await FilePicker.Default.PickAsync(options);
    if (result != null)
    {
        filePath = result.FullPath;
    }
    // add this code
    StateHasChanged();
}
```

Hope it helps!